# Is "T : R → R defined by T(x) = 1" an isomorphism?

Tags: linear-algebra

In my textbook, I have come across the following linear transformation:

**T : R → R defined by T(x) = 1**

I am confused as to whether this transformation is an isomorphism or not. If all x in T(x) yield the same value, would this function not be one-to-one and thus not be an isomorphism?

Comment: Correct. I think that's all there is to this.

Comment: In fact, this transformation is not even linear, so it is not isomorphism..

Answer (score 2):

You're right, this is a constant function on $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ so it is not even one-to-one (injective) let alone bijective.

However, note that this function is not linear (because $T(0) \neq 0$), so we can't even talk about it being a linear-isomorphism.

Perhaps the textbook meant something like:

> Consider the linear transformation (whose value on the basis $\{1\}$ of $\Bbb{R}$) defined by $T(1) = 1$.

In this case, what it means is that for all $x \in \Bbb{R}$, $T(x) = x \cdot T(1) = x \cdot 1 = x$. i.e $T(x) = x$. This on the other hand is clearly linear and is an isomorphism.